# How to display result from two states after submitting a form

Tags: reactjs

I have two states , INPUT1 and INPUT2.
i am calling a function to setState them with new values.
then i am rendering the result using a const value.
it is quickly getting rendered without submitting the values.
However i want to use the submit button to render the result.
so i am trying to create result state and pass the values to the same.
but i need help. i am getting lot of errors.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    class AppComponent2 extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          input1: '',
          input2 : ''
        };

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      }

      handleInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        console.log(target); // event.target is saved in target.
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        console.log(value); //target.value is saved in value.
        const name = target.name; //target.name is saved in name.
        console.log(name);

        this.setState({
          [name]: value

        });
      }
      handleSubmit(event) {
        alert('This is input1: ' + this.state.input1);
        alert('This is input2: ' + this.state.input2);
        event.preventDefault();
      }


  render() {

    const result = this.state.input1 && this.state.input2 ? parseInt(this.state.input1) + parseInt(this.state.input2) : null;
    return (

        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 class="display-3">Add 2 Numbers</h1>
                <hr class="my-4"/>

                <fieldset>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <label class="control-label" for="readOnlyInput"> </label>
                        <input  value={this.state.input1} onChange={this.handleInputChange} class="form-control" id="input1" name="input1" type="text" placeholder="input here…" />
                        <input value={this.state.input2} onChange={this.handleInputChange} class="form-control" id="input2"  name="input2" type="text" placeholder="input here…" />


                    </form>

                </fieldset>

                    <p> This is the result {result} </p>

        </div>




    );
  }
}

export default AppComponent2;
```

Comment: Please add errors thrown and code you have tried, surely console logs are not causing errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting state on `onChange` method and displaying same in `result` variable. If you want to display after submit, then you need to `setState` in `handleSubmit` method and display it in render. You can do as below:

```
handleInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        console.log(target); // event.target is saved in target.
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        console.log(value); //target.value is saved in value.
        const name = target.name; //target.name is saved in name.
        console.log(name);

        this.setState({
          [name]: value

        });
      }
      handleSubmit(event) {
        this.setState({val1: this.state.input1, val2: this.state.input2});
        alert('This is input1: ' + this.state.input1);
        alert('This is input2: ' + this.state.input2);
        event.preventDefault();
      }
```

And then in your `render()` method you can define your variable as below:

```
const result = this.state.val1 && this.state.val2 ? parseInt(this.state.val1) + parseInt(this.state.val2) : null;
```

Comment: this was helpful. thanks a ton. its working now. i was confused with adding the state variables too. so i declared a result state. and passed the added value to it , then rendered it.  i am pretty new to react. this state and props are still a bit confusing to me. but i am loving the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I created a `finalresult` function and passed my 2 updated states.
and then added them in a const, and then passed it to result variable.

```
finalresult(){

    const result = this.state.input1 && this.state.input2 ? parseInt(this.state.input1) + parseInt(this.state.input2) : null;
    this.setState({ 
            result : result 

    });


  }
```

then I rendered it in the `return` function.

```
render() {
        const result = parseInt(this.state.result);

return (

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-3">Add 2 Numbers</h1>
            <hr class="my-4"/>

            <fieldset>

                    <label class="control-label" for="readOnlyInput"> </label>
                    <input  value={this.state.input1} onChange={this.handleInputChange} class="form-control" id="input1" name="input1" type="text" placeholder="input here…" />
                    <input value={this.state.input2} onChange={this.handleInputChange} class="form-control" id="input2"  name="input2" type="text" placeholder="input here…" />
                    <input onClick={()=>this.finalresult()} type="submit" value="Submit" />



            </fieldset>


                <p> Result is {result} </p> 
    </div>




);
}
```